# Correct way to use indexer in Parallel.For

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, parallel-processing

I have a method which generates a (Waveform) bitmap based on a specific (Waveform)-function (in the examples below I am simply using Math.Sin to simplify things). Up until now this method was "serial" (no threads) however some of the functions used are relatively time consuming so I tried using `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach`, but I guess the index variable I use must get "corrupted" (or at least have another value than what I expect) the graphics being generated will either contain "spikes" or strange lines between points that are not neighbours.

Here first is my serial version (which works):

```
Point[] points = new Point[rect.Width];
byte[] ptTypes = new byte[rect.Width];
for (int i = 0; i < rect.Width; i++)
{
    double phase = MathUtil.WrapRad((MathUtil.PI2 / (rect.Width / 1d)) * i);
    double value = waveform.ValueAtPhase(phase);
    newPoint = new Point(rect.Left + i,
        rect.Top + (int) (halfHeight + (value * -1d * halfHeight * scaleY)));
    points[i] = newPoint;
    if (i == 0)
        ptTypes[i] = (byte)PathPointType.Start;
    else
        ptTypes[i] = (byte)PathPointType.Line;
}
using (GraphicsPath wavePath = new GraphicsPath(points, ptTypes))
{
    gph.DrawPath(wavePen, wavePath);
}
```

As you can see the code simply uses 2 arrays (one for Points and one for PointTypes) so the order these values are inserted into the array should not matter, as long as the values are inserted into the correct elements of the arrays.

Next example is using Parallel.For (to simplify the examples I have omitted the creation of the arrays and the actual draw method):

```
Parallel.For(0, rect.Width,
       i =>
{
    double phase = MathUtil.WrapRad((MathUtil.PI2 / (rect.Width / 1d)) * i);
    double value = Math.Sin(phase);//waveform.ValueAtPhase(phase);
    newPoint = new Point(rect.Left + i,
        rect.Top + (int)(halfHeight + (value * -1d * halfHeight * scaleY)));
    points[i] = newPoint;
    if (i == 0)
        ptTypes[i] = (byte)PathPointType.Start;
    else
        ptTypes[i] = (byte)PathPointType.Line;
});
```

Lastly I tried using a Partitioner with a Parallel.ForEach loop, but that did not fix the problem either:

```
var rangePartitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, rect.Width);
Parallel.ForEach(rangePartitioner, (range, loopState) =>
{
    for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
    {
        double phase = MathUtil.WrapRad((MathUtil.PI2 / (rect.Width / 1d)) * i);
        double value = Math.Sin(phase);//waveform.ValueAtPhase(phase);
        newPoint = new Point(rect.Left + i,
            rect.Top + (int)(halfHeight + (value * -1d * halfHeight * scaleY)));
        points[i] = newPoint;
        if (i == 0)
            ptTypes[i] = (byte)PathPointType.Start;
        else
            ptTypes[i] = (byte)PathPointType.Line;
    }
});
```

Pelle

Comment: what is the problem ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
newPoint = new Point(rect.Left + i, rect.Top + (int)(halfHeight + (value * -1d * halfHeight * scaleY)));
```

newPoint is not scoped to your `for()` loop - it's likely threads are updating it before you get to the next line `points[i] = newPoint;`

Change it to `var newPoint = ...`

Otherwise, your `Parallel.For` looks fine.

Also, does this have different behavior?

`Math.Sin(phase);//waveform.ValueAtPhase(phase);`

Providing ValueAtPhase does not modify anything, you should be able to use it within the loop.

Comment: You are absolutely rigtht and chaning the code into "points[i] = new Point(.." (not using the newPoint) var fixed the Parallel.For loop (it seams), however the Parallel.ForEach (with the Partitioner) is still not good !?

Comment: @PelleLiljendal Typically Parallel.ForEach is for iterating IEnumerables - and you are given an item for each pass. It's not a good candidate for this situation. My best guess is that `Partitioner.Create(0, rect.Width);` is somehow off. `Parallel.ForEach` and `Parallel.For` behave in the same way (as `for` and `foreach` behave in the same way) - so this only points to the partitioner being broken. I would stick to `Parallel.For` for your use case, and only use `Parallel.ForEach` if you have a collection.

Comment: ValueAtPhase should be threadsafe, however in order to eliminate that this was the problem I temporary changed the code into using Math.Sin in stead